# How can I map Samsung Galaxy S4 as a removeable storage

Tags: windows-7, windows, portable

Is there anyway for me to get to the Samsung S4 (running Android Version 4.2.2) via the Windows 7 CLI (command line interface)?  The phone is showing up as a Portable Media Device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Samsung](http://www.techoxygen.com/samsung-sidesync-apk-free/) SideSync software to sync your device with the Windows 7, 8 and 10. This is a very easy way to connect and use device interface through PC or laptop.